# Xamarin.Android How to make a 'wav' file the default push notification sound for the app?

Tags: c#, push-notification, xamarin.android

Goal: Set custom wav as default push notification sound for app.

I have a wave file that resides in the "FilesDir" on Android. I used Xamarin.Essentials FileSystem helper to create the file in FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, its actually a voice recording.

The exact location of the wav file upon in inspection in Debug is:

/data/user/o/com.company.appname/files/fileName.Wav

I need to make this file the default push notification sound for my app.
Currently I have a notification channel set up, but the notification sound (and which works as intended) used resides  in res/raw.

How can I achieve this?

It seems that I cannot make it the default push notification sound from its current location. I would have to copy it to Ringtone folder or to res/raw folder but how can I do this (copy the file to the respective location from where it can be used as notification sound) dynamically when the app is running please? Is it even possible to make a file transfer within the APK?

This is what I tried when creating the push notification channel but it did not work:

```
//Create two notif channels, the urgent channel 
// should use a custom wav as notification sound
private void createNotificationChannels()
    {
        try
        {
            // the urgent channel
            var urgentChannelName = GetString(Resource.String.noti_chan_urgent);
            var urgentChannelDescription = GetString(Resource.String.noti_chan_urgent_description);

            // the informational channel
            var infoChannelName = GetString(Resource.String.noti_chan_info);
            var infoChannelDescrption = GetString(Resource.String.noti_chan_info_description);

            // set the vibration patterns for the channels
            long[] urgentVibrationPattern = { 100, 30, 100, 30, 100, 200, 200, 30, 200, 30, 200, 200, 100, 30, 100, 30, 100, 100, 30, 100, 30, 100, 200, 200, 30, 200, 30, 200, 200, 100, 30, 100, 30, 100 };
            long[] infoVibrationPattern = { 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400 };

            // Creating common Audio Attributes for both channels
            var alarmAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .SetContentType(AudioContentType.Sonification)
                .SetUsage(AudioUsageKind.Notification).Build();

            // get path of custom sound recording to use as push notification
            var recordingFileDestinationPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, AppConstants.CUSTOM_ALERT_FILENAME);

            //**This is where I am trying to create the URI for the custom wav file for notification, which resides in FilesDir**
            Android.Net.Uri urgentAlarmUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(recordingFileDestinationPath);

            Android.Net.Uri infoAlarmUri = RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification);


            var chan1 = new NotificationChannel(PRIMARY_CHANNEL_ID, urgentChannelName, NotificationImportance.High)
            {
                Description = urgentChannelDescription
            };

            var chan2 = new NotificationChannel(SECONDARY_CHANNEL_ID, infoChannelName, NotificationImportance.Default)
            {
                Description = infoChannelDescrption
            };


            // set the urgent channel properties
            chan1.EnableLights(true);
            chan1.LightColor = Color.Red;
            chan1.SetSound(urgentAlarmUri, alarmAttributes);
            chan1.EnableVibration(true);
            chan1.SetVibrationPattern(urgentVibrationPattern);               
            chan1.SetBypassDnd(true);
            chan1.LockscreenVisibility = NotificationVisibility.Public;

            // set the info channel properties
            chan2.EnableLights(true);
            chan2.LightColor = Color.Red;
            chan2.SetSound(infoAlarmUri, alarmAttributes);
            chan2.EnableVibration(true);
            chan2.SetVibrationPattern(infoVibrationPattern);
            chan2.SetBypassDnd(false);
            chan2.LockscreenVisibility = NotificationVisibility.Public;


            var manager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);

            // create chan1  which is the urgent notifications channel
            manager.CreateNotificationChannel(chan1);
            manager.CreateNotificationChannel(chan2);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

The there was no sound for the urgent channel with the above code.
If I load the sound from res/raw it works fine. If i put the recording beforehand in res/raw it would probably work, but the sound is recorded custom at runtime...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Xamarin Essentials Source code for `FileSystem.AppDataDirectory` for Android,

https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/blob/master/Xamarin.Essentials/FileSystem/FileSystem.android.cs#L14

You're saving your recorded sound file to internal storage (the files directory).  The Files directory is a private directory that is only accessible by your application.  Neither the user or the OS can access this file.  You'll have to save the file in either [Public External Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=macos#public-external-files) or [Private External Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=macos#private-external-files).  It depends on whether or not you want your recorded sound file accessible by the MediaStore content provider.

Comment: you're right thank you for the tip. I have a working solution and posted it below.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do this, and might help someone trying to do same. Here is the solution:

As @SharpMoibileCode stated, when using Xamarin Essentials File system helpers, and specifically when saving the recording using the path **FileSystem.AppDataDirectory** it saves it in the **Internal Storage**. This has a path like this:

> /data/user/0/com.company.appname/files/customsoundfilename.wav

In order to customize the Push Notification sound for the channel at run-time, the sound file has to be saved to the **Public External Storage** namely **Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory** which has a path like this:

> /storage/emulated/0/.../

Now permissions to write to external storage are needed in order to write/read to/from external storage. So these need to be added to manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

But its not sufficient. Permission has to be asked right before the external storage is accessed like this(using NuGet plugin Current Activity for Android project here to get the current activity):

```
var currentActivity = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity;
            int requestCode=1;

            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(currentActivity, new string[] {
                Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage,
                Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage
            }, requestCode);
```

if permission is granted then proceed and copy file to external storage:

```
var recordingFileExternalPath = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path, AppConstants.CUSTOM_ALERT_FILENAME);

            if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(Android.App.Application.Context, Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage) == (int)Permission.Granted)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (File.Exists(recordingFileExternalPath))
                    {
                        File.Delete(recordingFileExternalPath);
                    }

                    File.Copy(filePath, recordingFileExternalPath);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                UserDialogs.Instance.Alert("Permission to write to External Storage not approved, cannot save settings.", "Permission Denied", "Ok");
            }
```

And now finally set the sound copied above as notification for the channel:

```
try
            {
                // the urgent channel
                var urgentChannelName = GetString(Resource.String.noti_chan_urgent);
                var urgentChannelDescription = GetString(Resource.String.noti_chan_urgent_description);


                // set the vibration patterns for the channels
                long[] urgentVibrationPattern = { 100, 30, 100, 30, 100, 200, 200, 30, 200, 30, 200, 200, 100, 30, 100, 30, 100, 100, 30, 100, 30, 100, 200, 200, 30, 200, 30, 200, 200, 100, 30, 100, 30, 100 };

                // Creating an Audio Attribute
                var alarmAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .SetContentType(AudioContentType.Speech)
                    .SetUsage(AudioUsageKind.Notification).Build();

                // Create the uri for the alarm file

                var recordingFileDestinationPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path, AppConstants.CUSTOM_ALERT_FILENAME);

                Android.Net.Uri urgentAlarmUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(recordingFileDestinationPath);



                var chan1 = new NotificationChannel(PRIMARY_CHANNEL_ID, urgentChannelName, NotificationImportance.High)
                {
                    Description = urgentChannelDescription
                };


                // set the urgent channel properties
                chan1.EnableLights(true);
                chan1.LightColor = Color.Red;
                chan1.SetSound(urgentAlarmUri, alarmAttributes);
                chan1.EnableVibration(true);
                chan1.SetVibrationPattern(urgentVibrationPattern);               
                chan1.SetBypassDnd(true);
                chan1.LockscreenVisibility = NotificationVisibility.Public;



                var manager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);

                // create chan1  which is the urgent notifications channel
                manager.CreateNotificationChannel(chan1);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```